# 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in path

Tags: python, phantomjs

I have tried many ways to solve this problem but I kept on getting this error `"'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH".`

I have tried adding the path into the environment variable:

```
def __init__(self,base_url):
    self._phantomjs_path = os.path.join(os.curdir,'phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
    self._base_url = base_url
    self._driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(self._phantomjs_path)
```

I expect the output of the weather forecast to be displayed. Can anyone help please?

Comment: `PhantomJS` is deprecated. Use headless Chrome instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Guy is correct the phantomjs is depretiated so use either chrome driver or the firefox driver with the headless option, other options are available [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) but I have not tested them all yet.

Download chrome driver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and add to PATH this is the code to use the chrome driver with the headless option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

base_url = "your_url_here"

driver.get(base_url)

driver.close()
```

Or for firefox driver download from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and add to PATH this is the code to use the firefox driver with headless option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

base_url = "your_url_here"

driver.get(base_url)

driver.close()
```